# RestTemplate URL Not enough variable values available to expand

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, restful-url, resttemplate

I need to pass 2 parameters to the REST URL. Like this:

http://localhost:8080/test/rest/userName/id

I'm trying something like this which obviously is not correct. Please help:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(localUrl+"{userName}"+"/"+"{id}", Details.class);
```

**EDIT:**

I tired this too but same error:

```
String param = "{userName}/{id}";
restTemplate.getForObject(localUrl+param, Details.class);
```

Thanks

Harish